# How to restrict files to UTF-8 encoded only in Angular file upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multipartform-data, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload to upload a text file.

```
<span type="file" class="btn" ngf-select ng-model="fileUser" name="fileUser" ngf-pattern="'.txt,.TXT'" ngf-accept="'text/plain'"> Select File </span>
```

Is there any way to accept only UTF-8 encoded text file and reject any othe r type of encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not natively supported in `ng-file-upload` but you can create it yourself. Hook into `ngf-change` this way:

```
ngf-change="checkEncoding($files, $file, $newFiles, $duplicateFiles, $invalidFiles, $event)"
```

Include [**`encoding.js`**](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js) in your app. When the user select a `.txt` file, load the content of the file by `FileReader` and use `encoding.js` to test the encoding :

```
$scope.checkEncoding = function(files, file, newFiles, duplicateFiles, invalidFiles, event) {
  if (!event.target.files) return
  var testFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var content = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var encoding = Encoding.detect(content);
    if (encoding != 'UTF8') {
      //alert to the user, reset the file ng-model whatever ...
    }
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(testFile)
}
```

---

Here is a working plunkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/1UM9NDpNgRbJ13R67xuf?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In this process to find encoding, will the memory usage increase drastically if I upload a large file of  size in GBs ?

Comment: @SreeraghAR, thank you for accepting the answer. Yes, I believe so, but it will be released again as soon the task end. I did not know you wanted to upload files in GB -size. There is a method to `slice` the reading (so you can have for example a progressbar) perhaps it can be used to halt the process and still pass a useful chunk to encoding.js. Will look into it this afternoon, I am quite busy right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Using *slice* solved the problem. Memory usage became stable. Thanks

Comment: @SreeraghAR, great you got it to work! Nice to hear it really is doable with slice.